# How to gather email adresses through an android activity

Tags: android, forms, email, newsletter

I realeased an android app and within the niche market I got a good acceptance. Now I want to create a weekly e-newsletter.

I want to create an activity that allows users to write their email account and send it over to me, but I have no idea how to do it. I searched and searched, but still couldn't find anything.

How can I allow users to send their e-mail addresses to me and how can I save them in order to distribute a newsletter?

Many thanks,
Isaac

Answer (score 0):

How about you create an EditText and style it to what you want and a button to submit the text in the EditText to a API?
Do you have any backend communication on your niche app? If so then just create an endpoint so that your app can send the emails to a server you control and then enrol them in the newsletter.

Comment: How can I program that EditText + Button to send an e-mail to my e-mail account? Thank you for answering

Comment: You need one of 2 things, or an Intent to open Gmail with your email as the receiver, the bad thing is that anyone can see your email address which can leave you open to some spam. The second option is to have your app communicate with an API, you'll need to develop and host the endpoint but it would shield you from people knowing the email address. I don't have a lot of context here but if you don't have any APIs developed then you should go with the first, if you have your own backend go with the latter option.